# J-locate on joomla platform

Tags: php, joomla

I created an external link for J-locate plugin for Joomla that would help show a certain locations I need on the map since there is no way to set a default location through the plugin. It goes something like this: **view=jlocate&state=nc&zip=27604&radius=10**

I am trying to figure out a way to get rid of the state filter so it doesn't restrict the zipcodes closest location by the states. Is it possible to put multiple states in the external link I made? It would be nice if it works so it filters through all states, i tried putting something like the following: view=jlocate&state=nc&ca&fl&zip=27604&radius=10 so it would go through multiple states but it only selects the first one, so if the zipcode is not in NC, it wouldn't find it.

My goal is to make the map available so anyone can search all states by the zipcode field alone without putting in a state. This will resolve a border line locations that i am facing right now due to the fact that its filtering states.

Thank you in advance for any positive help.

here is the link to the plugin i am using: http://joomlavida.com/jlocate-joomla-store-locator-demo?zip=33761&state=FL

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the component. 
The correct way to pass a list could be an array

```
&state[]=nc&state[]=va&state[]=nj
```

but since you want to do without, why not omit it? If it's forced somewhere beyond your control you could still unset() it.

Otherwise in the unlikely scenario that the programmer is not doing server-side sql injection filtering, pass

```
&state=%
```

where % is the wildcard for SQL.